# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting following error when I try to run my Android application in Eclipse . But this is happening with only single project in same workspace.

```
JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of   Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
D:\Projects\<AppName>\hs_err_pid5752.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

What I done:

1. By reading posts I got to know that this may be any memory error(hard disk sector dump error). So, I remove my app from my workspace to different one.
2. Installed new version of java, etc.

But of them is working.

**Complete Error in log file :**

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=5024, tid=920
  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0164b800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=920, stack(0x01690000,0x016e0000)]

Stack: [0x01690000,0x016e0000],  sp=0x016df438,  free space=317k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x170511]
V  [jvm.dll+0x16a6b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2082f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x208b6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2e5dd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2e889]
V  [jvm.dll+0x77bd1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x77f8b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12a1b1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14ac6a]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa9eef]
C  [javaw.exe+0x13ca]
C  [javaw.exe+0x1e3c]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa5b1]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa63b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ed6c]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6377b]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6374e]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xc2

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0164b800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=920, stack(0x01690000,0x016e0000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01543e08 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01542238 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01542210
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x0157e1f8
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x0157e1f8 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x0157e230
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x0157e230 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01573718
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01573718 done
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x01542210 done

Dynamic libraries:
0x00060000 - 0x0008f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x774e0000 - 0x7761c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x75ee0000 - 0x75fb4000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75900000 - 0x7594a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77670000 - 0x77710000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75e10000 - 0x75ebc000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x75c00000 - 0x75c19000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76ca0000 - 0x76d41000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x772f0000 - 0x773b9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x75dc0000 - 0x75e0e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77010000 - 0x7701a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76d50000 - 0x76ded000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x74580000 - 0x7471e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76df0000 - 0x76e47000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x77650000 - 0x7766f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75b30000 - 0x75bfc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x6b790000 - 0x6b84e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x5f390000 - 0x5f6df000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71520000 - 0x71527000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x771c0000 - 0x771f5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x75ec0000 - 0x75ec6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x738a0000 - 0x738d2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75ed0000 - 0x75ed5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x728f0000 - 0x728fc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x72790000 - 0x727b0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x727b0000 - 0x727c3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x72580000 - 0x7266b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:D:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\android.jar;D:\android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-8\libs\maps.jar 
java_command: com.cipl.CommonCollection.Test
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\android-ndk-r8c;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;D:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;D:\android-sdk-windows\tools;D:\Bucketo\Tools\apache-ant-1.9.0-bin\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin;D:\android-sdk-windows;C:\cygwin\bin;D:\Bucketo\Tools\eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32_classic\eclipse;
USERNAME=akhilesh.tiwari
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 1935764k(131636k free), swap 3871528k(1391032k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.21-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_21-b11), built on Apr  4 2013 04:43:10 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Wed Jun 19 19:17:55 2013
elapsed time: 0 seconds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply changing your workspace should do the trick.

Answer (score 16):

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Delete the **.metadata** folder from the workspace directory.
3. Open Eclipse and import the projects from the workspace (do not copy these because they are already in it).

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this issue in my project.
Simply deleted the existing server from Eclipse Server view.
Then created a new server with my existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Core dumps (your core dumps must be disabled).

To enable core dump

```
unlimit -c unlimited
```

*close eclipse first

Comment: This is to enable core dumps on Linux not for enabling minidumps on Windows

Answer (score 0):

One of the `jvmargs` was causing the problem for me when starting the jetty ant task with jrebel args. Removing the jvmargs arguments and just running the the `mvn jetty:run` command with `-javaagent` pointed to `jrebel.jar` simply worked for me.